SQL query to get list of clients who have not ordered a specific zone (geographic territory) in 2024
I'm pretty new to SQL, and I did try searching for this answer but I can't find a question similar enough that I could learn from it and modify it to work for my scenario.
I'm trying to get a list of clients and their order info to include only clients who have not ordered a specific geography in 2024 YTD (these orders are for ads/commercials). I need data so I can create a report showing, for the targeted clients, which zones they DID order, and how much revenue they spent per zone, per month.
This would give me data for every order line for every order, which I would then roll up to the order level using a pivot table. I can't think of another way to do it.
The tables at issue are broken out like this (more columns available but I don't think they're relevant):
Client:
| ClientID | ClientName |

Order:
| OrderID | ClientID | OrderStartDate | OrderEndDate |

OrderLine:
| LineNumber | OrderID | ZoneID | AdUnitCost | AdUnitCount | LineStartDate | LineStopDate |

Zone:
| ZoneID | ZoneName |

An orderline might look like this:



LineNumber
OrderID
ZoneID
AdUnitCost
AdUnitCount
LineStartDate
LineStopDate




87
1234567
55851
$250
10
08/19/2024
08/25/2024



I know how to pull all of the order lines for all client orders but I don't know how to sum them by client while only including order lines for client who did NOT order zone XXXX in 2024. I hope this makes sense.
This is as far as I can get:
SELECT 
    C.Szcompany AS ClientName,
    TO_NUMBER(Ol.ulordernumber, 38, 0) AS OrderNumber,
    TO_NUMBER(OL.ullinenumber, 38, 0) AS LineNumber,
    r.szdescription AS Zone,
    DATE(ol.ulstartdate) AS StartDate,
    DATE(ol.ulenddate) AS StopDate,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.ullinespots, 38, 0) AS AdUnitCount,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.drate, 38, 2) AS AdUnitCost 
FROM
    VW_X_ORDER O
JOIN
    VW_X_CUSTOMER C ON c.ulid = o.ulcustomerid
JOIN
    VW_X_ORDER_LINE OL ON oL.ulordernumber = o.ulordernumber
JOIN  
    VW_X_REGION R ON r.ulid = ol.ulregionid
WHERE 
    ol.ullinespots > 0
    AND StartDate >= DATE('01/01/2024')
    AND StopDate <= DATE('12/31/2024')


Please read [mre]

Add a tag for the dbms used. (TO_NUMBER and DATE are product specific functions.)

You could create a subquery to grab the ClientIds that have ordered from that zone in 2024 and then, in your where clause add customerId not in clientIds from the subquery.
So something like
WITH ClientsWithSpecificZoneOrderIn2024 AS (
    SELECT c.ulid AS ClientID
    FROM VW_X_CUSTOMER c
    JOIN VW_X_ORDER o ON c.ulid = o.ulcustomerid
    JOIN VW_X_ORDER_LINE ol ON o.ulordernumber = ol.ulordernumber
    WHERE ZoneID = #####
    AND ol.ulstartdate >= DATE('01/01/2024')
    AND ol.ulenddate <= DATE('12/31/2024')
)

SELECT
    c.szcompany AS ClientName,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.ulordernumber, 38, 0) AS OrderNumber,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.ullinenumber, 38, 0) AS LineNumber,
    r.szdescription AS Zone,
    DATE(ol.ulstartdate) AS StartDate,
    DATE(ol.ulenddate) AS StopDate,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.ullinespots, 38, 0) AS AdUnitCount,
    TO_NUMBER(ol.drate, 38, 2) AS AdUnitCost
FROM
    VW_X_ORDER o
JOIN
    VW_X_CUSTOMER c ON o.ulcustomerid= c.ulid
JOIN
    VW_X_ORDER_LINE ol ON o.ulordernumber = ol.ulordernumber
JOIN
    VW_X_REGION r ON r.ulid = ol.ulregionid
WHERE
    c.ulid NOT IN (SELECT ClientID FROM ClientsWithSpecificZoneOrderIn2024 )



Thank you! Your suggestion was almost perfect. I added those same dates from the CTE to the other select statement and it worked - appreciate your help! I upvoted but I'm brand new here so it won't show.
